# creating a database in javascript using xampp

Tags: javascript, database, xampp

I am wanting to use a database in javascript. I am familiar only with xampp for databases. With the code snippet .openDatabase('test1'.x .x .x) A new DB 'test1' is created if one doesn't exist, otherwise it opens 'test1'. Where is this DB found? And probably more importantly,how do I make use xampp instead? Of course should I actually be using javascript at all?
I do understand that what I am asking is not that secure. At this point in time, I don't care. I need to get some sort of practice before adding in extra levels of difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

For your need, you can see the tutorial from: https://www.airpair.com/javascript/complete-expressjs-nodejs-mongodb-crud-skeleton

other tutorial:
http://teknosains.com/i/simple-crud-nodejs-mysql

**For other CRUD with JavaScript Tutorials:**
[https://google/MkVg6Q](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&client=firefox-b&biw=1304&bih=697&q=crud%20node%20js%20tutorial&oq=crud%20node%20js%20tutor&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i22i30l3.4141.5258.0.6774.6.6.0.0.0.0.140.733.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.6.731...0.raF2_aasDxE)

Comment: Thank you. I have started looking into Node.js. This helps a lot

Comment: @gavin glad to help you:) so, mark my answer as your choosed answer please.. see this link to mark the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers